# Sending alerts when an instance is created inside AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

Need to receive emails when someone creates an EC2 instance in AWS. I have tried using cloudwatch but that doesn't seem to work for me. It says insufficient data. Is there a better way to do it?

[Creating CloudWatch Alarms for CloudTrail Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html#cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail-ec2-instance-changes)

Comment: Try this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226818/4398385

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SNS notification for ec2 instance creation and termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226290/sns-notification-for-ec2-instance-creation-and-termination)

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : Create a Cloud watch Rule to notifiy the creation . As per the lifecycle of EC2 Instance when lauch button is pressed  . Instance goes from Pending state to Running state . So create the Rule for Pending state

[Create a Cloud watch Rule as specified in the image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WrU2.png)

Step2 : Create a Step function . Because cloud Trail logs all the event in the account with a delay of atleast 20 min . This step function is usefull if you want the name of user who has created the instance .

```
{
  "StartAt": "Wait",
  "States": {
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 1800,
      "Next": "Ec2-Alert"
    },
   "Ec2-Alert":{
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:321039853697:function:EC2-Creation-Alert",
     "End": true  

  }
  }
}
```

Step3 : Create a SNS topic for notification

Step4 : Write a lambda function to fetch the log from cloud trail and get the user name who has created the instance .

```
import json
import os
import subprocess
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')
    client1 = boto3.client('sns')
    Instance=event["detail"]["instance-id"]     
    response = client.lookup_events(
    LookupAttributes=[
        {
            'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName',
            'AttributeValue': Instance
        },
    ],
    MaxResults=1)

    test=response['Events']

    st="".join(str(x) for x in test)
    print(st)
    user=st.split("Username")[1]
    finalname=user.split(",")
    Creator=finalname[0]
    #print(st[st.find("Username")])

    Email= "Hi All ,\n\n\n The User%s has created new EC2-Instance in QA account and the Instance id is %s \n\n\n Thank you \n\n\n Regard's lamda"%(Creator,Instance)



    response = client1.publish(
    TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:321039853697:Ec2-Creation-Alert',
    Message=Email

)

    # TODO implement
    return {

        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

Note: This code trigger an notification if the instance is changed from stop state to running state.

Answer (score 0):

To get an email alert whenever a new resource is created in your AWS account, you can setup an EventBridge rule with SNS topic as target.

You can create a eventbridge rule with the pattern the following pattern and add target as SNS.

```
{ "detail": {
"configurationItem": {
  "configurationItemStatus": ["ResourceDiscovered"],
  "resourceType": ["AWS::S3::Bucket"]
},
"messageType": ["ConfigurationItemChangeNotification"]   
},
"detail-type": ["Config Configuration Item Change"], 
"source": ["aws.config"] 
}
```

What does this do it checks configuration changes from config triggers the eventbridge rule and sends out an email with the template you provide. Additionally, configure the input transformer in the target section and add a template of your choice to customize your alert mail

For Ec2 instance replace the resource type with "AWS:EC2:Instance"

[This is how the email alert looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qow6j.png)

For more information, check this:

https://medium.com/@TechStoryLines/receive-sns-alerts-when-new-resources-are-created-in-your-aws-account-db749b16445f

https://techstorylines.hashnode.dev/receive-sns-alerts-when-new-resources-are-created-in-your-aws-account

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34644380)

Comment: Got it., thank you for the feedback. will remember this in the future.